# Font Icons from Fontastic works fine in my Storybook but if I use the Storybook in my react app project, it won't work. How to fix this?

Tags: reactjs, components, icons, config, storybook

I've created a storybook that contains an Icon component. The actual look or how to use the component is just like this,

```
<Icon iconName="user" />
...or
<UserIcon />
```

Both are working in my Storybook stories. And what it looks like in DOM Elements is,

```
<i className="icon-user ...">
  ::before
</>
```

And in DOM Styles, the icon CSS is displayed as,

```
.icon-user:before {
  content: "\79";
}
```

But, when I use the Storybook in my separate react app project, the Icon component loads but the icon itself won't work.

Below are my files and codes.

...

This is my .storybook/main.js

```
import '../src/main.css';

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on.*' },
  options: {
    storySort: {
     order: ['Icon', 'Controls', '*'],
     // method: 'alphabetical',
    },
  },
};
```

And this is my .storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx|js|jsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require('postcss'),
        },
      },
    }
  ],
  typescript: {
    check: true, // type-check stories during Storybook build
  },
  staticDirs: ['../public'],
}
```

And this is my .storybook/preview-head.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styles.css" />
```

And in my src/main.css

```
@import '../public/styles.css';
```

public folder contents:

```
> fonts
icons-reference.html
styles.css
```

And what's inside in my styles.css is

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "icons";
  src:url("fonts/icons.eot");
  src:url("fonts/icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/icons.woff") format("woff"),
    url("fonts/icons.ttf") format("TrueType"),
    url("fonts/icons.svg#icons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

...

.icon-user:before {
  content: "\79";
}
```

And in my react app, when I used the Icon component from Storybook, it looks like this,

```
<UserIcon />
```

I only see,

```
<i className="icon-user ...">
</>
```

the ::before pseudo-element won't appear in DOM Styles.